# How to apply a map widget in a layout?

Tags: android, google-maps

I understand there is a new method to apply google maps to a new application/activity in new versions of android studio. However I have not found anything about how to add a google map "widget" to a layout already created. Essentially I am trying to place a map in a layout to later be used as a fragment to another layout. I already have my API key but not sure how to implement this to my project. Any useful guides or hints towards this problem? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can find all the useful links pertaining to your question [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/maps.html). Since you have tagged/mentioned Android I am assuming your question is particularly for the Android platform. The latest version of the MAPS API is v2.

As far as placing a Google Map "Widget" goes, try using the MapFragment class which should be able to help (From what I understand).

A few recommended reads that should be very helpful:
1. [MapFragment](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapfragment)
2. [MapView](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView.html)
..and last but not the least...
3. [MapObjects](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map#mapfragment)